# php 5.5.30 / Joomla 1.5 component outputs an extra newline in Prod vs. Dev

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following Controller in a component in Joomla 1.5/ PHP 5.5.30 on my Mac (OSX 10.11):

```
<?php
jimport ( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );
class MyController extends JController {
 function display() {
    ob_end_clean ();
 }
}
?>
```

when I call this controller via the browser and view-source, I get a *completely* empty page, as I would expect.

However, when I commit this code to my Production box (Centos 6 running PHP 5.5.30), and navigate to the same endpoint in the same browser, I get a page with a newline character in it.

Can anyone tell me, or guess, as to why the platforms would differ this way in terms of the output?

Comment: How do you copy/sync the files.  It may be the encoding of the file.  If, for example, you have a file with UTF-8 with BOM you can get some extra output.  I found that one out the hard way when debugging.

Comment: The `EOL` (End Of Line) character on OSX is the carriage return (`\r`). In linux, the `EOL` is the new line/line feed (`\n`). In windows, it's both together (`\r\n`). It's possible that the browser is ignoring the `\r` that it gets while running on mac, but doesn't ignore the `\n` that it gets from linux. Either way, a "blank page" still sends an `EOL` character.

Comment: I have since found that calling ob_end_clean(); *twice* gives the same output from both platforms - i.e. a completely empty file.  Does this confirm or negate your suspicions?

Comment: this is not by platform,perhaps it's happen by configs like php.ini

Comment: Why do you have the close tag? Get rid of that. Also why aren't you testing to see if you are inside Joomla?